# How to reuse UITableViewCell for different type of cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that has different types of cells in it.The common approach is to have different `UITableViewCell`s and reuse them depending on the data object.

Now, I have 9 different types of data objects. But my view is similar to the Facebook feed view with like button, comments button, user image and user name. Only the centre view changes based on the data object.

My question is, should I use 9 different type of cells with a common class for these elements or should I use one cell and add the centre view as and when the cell is created?

Currently my approach is to use one cell and add the centre view. Will the `UITableViewCell` be re-used if we follow that approach?

Comment: cell will be reused if you use tableView.dequeueCell, no matter what you have done in your cell

Comment: logic is yours, should I use 9 different type of cells also you show in based on condition, same condition used in single cell also and change the height based on condition, sry we dont know what your project contains ,customize yourself

Answer (score 1):

The table view cells will always be reused if you initialize the cell with `reuseIdentifier:` and use the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method on the table view.

As far whether to use a single `UITableViewCell` subclass or several, it depends on how much is different between each of your 9 content types. If they all contain the same UI elements, using 1 subclass makes sense. Otherwise, you can create multiple subclasses and still reuse the cells with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` as long as you pass in a different unique identifier for each subclass. Each subclass would be independently reused.

Here's what your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` could look like if you're using multiple cell classes:

```
NSString *primaryCellID = @"PrimaryCellID";
NSString *secondaryCellID = @"SecondaryCellID";

if (someCondition) {
    CustomTableViewCell1 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:primaryCellID];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell1 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:primaryCellID];
    }

    return cell;
}
else {
    CustomTableViewCell2 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:secondaryCellID];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell2 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:secondaryCellID];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This approach is good. How about the scenario where I have a footer in the cell with like and comment buttons which is common to all the cells. If I use different cells, how can I write common code for these elements? If I use the same cell, can I generate content and do an `addsubview:` inside the cell everytime the cell is dequeued?